# Check if input is blank

Tags: jquery

I want to check if input is blank or not. I am using simple code:

```
if ($("#logreg_content_input input").val().length > 0)
```

However this is not completely helping because user can enter spaces instead of characters. I want to remove spaces at the beginning and end of the input value entered by the user.

I tried this, but it is still counting spaces:

```
$.trim($("#logreg_content_input input"));
```

```js
$("body").on("click", "#join_username_next", function() {
  $.trim($("#logreg_content_input input"));
  if ($("#logreg_content_input input").val().length < 21 && $("#logreg_content_input input").val().length >2) {
    alert("zaaaa");
    //AJAX 
  } else {
    if ($("#logreg_content_input input").val().length > 2){
      $('#logreg_content_input').attr("data-placeholder", "Too long.. max 20 chars") 
    } else {
      $('#logreg_content_input').attr("data-placeholder", "Username..(min 3 chars)(A-z, 0-9, space)")
    }; 
    $('#logreg_content_input input').focus();
  }
});
```

How can I remove the spaces first, and check the input value without counting intervals at beginning or end?

For example: If I have entered value: `" Jessica "` count the length as `7`, not `9`

Solution:
`x = $("#logreg_content_input input").val().trim();

$("#logreg_content_input input").val(x);` after click.

Comment: Of course it makes no sense to try and “trim” a jQuery object. You want to trim the _value_, so do that.

Comment: what is intervals ?

Comment: $.trim($("#logreg_content_input input").val()); .. I tryed with adding **.val()** but it is still same...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this

```
if($("#logreg_content_input input").val().trim().length > 0)
```

instead of

```
if($("#logreg_content_input input").val().length > 0)
```

`trim()` removes the whitespace from the beginning and end of a string. In another words, it removes all newlines, spaces (including non-breaking spaces), and tabs from the beginning and end of the supplied string. If these whitespace characters occur in the middle of the string, they are preserved.